# Why Rails data loaded from Fixtures are broken?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

I got two fixture files for Locales and Translations.
Locales are loaded fine, but Translations are broken:

Fixture

```
translation_05064:
  id: 5064
  key: control.base_search_users.panel.title
  value: Поиск пользователей
  interpolations: 
  locale: ru
  locale_id: 16
  is_proc: false
```

Becomes the record:

```
#<Translation id: 5064, 
key: "control.base_search_users.panel.title", 
value: "Поиск пользователей", 
interpolations: nil, 
locale: nil, 
locale_id: 1019186233, 
is_proc: false>
```

For some reason **locale** instead of *'ru'* becomes nil, while **locale_ib** instead of *16* becomes *1019186233* for every fixture in a file.

I load fixtures such way:

```
require 'active_record/fixtures'
ActiveRecord::Fixtures.reset_cache  
fixtures_folder = File.join(Rails.root, 'test', 'fixtures')
fixtures = Dir[File.join(fixtures_folder, '*.yml')].map {|f| File.basename(f, '.yml') }
ActiveRecord::Fixtures.create_fixtures(fixtures_folder, fixtures)
```

Translation model

```
class Translation < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :key, :uniqueness => {:scope => :locale_id}
  validates :key, :locale, :locale_id, :value, :presence => true
  belongs_to :locale
  attr_accessible :key, :value, :locale_id, :locale
end
```

The migration

```
  class CreateTranslations < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      create_table :translations do |t|
        t.string  :key
        t.text    :value
        t.text    :interpolations
        t.string  :locale
        t.integer :locale_id
        t.boolean :is_proc, :default => false
      end
      add_index :translations, [:key, :locale]
    end
  end
```

I see in a test.log that inserts to DB contain broken data. When I load the fixture file in rails concole with `YAML.load_file 'test/fixtures/translations.yml'` I get correct Hash data.

Why that happens? How to fix that?
**Rails-2.3.8**, **PostgreSql-8.4**

---

**UPDATE:**
Tried named fixtures. In locales.yml:

```
locale_00016:
  id: 16
  code: ru
  name: Русский
```

and in translations.yml all **locale** key values set to locale_00016

```
translation_05064:
  id: 5064
  key: control.base_search_users.panel.title
  value: Поиск пользователей
  locale: locale_00016
  is_proc: false
```

**YES, that works!**

Translation *id* referred to existing and correct Locale record, but *locale* was still nil, to fix it I ran `Locale.find_by_code('ru').translations.update_all(:locale => 'ru')`

Comment: Is there still a problem if you remove the blank `interpolations` line in your fixture? It might be causing problems. You could either remove it or set it to `""`

Comment: I tried both, to delete interpolations line and to specify an empty value ''. That didn't solve the problem, but looking to the log I found that there is no **locale** field in inserts in case I delete **interpolation** lines from yml file. I'm feeling quite confused.

```Fixture Insert (1.5ms)  INSERT INTO "translations" ("id", "key", "value", "locale_id", "is_proc") VALUES (5502, 'sites.index.title', 'Сайты', 1019186233, 'f')```

Comment: In case I delete **interpolations** and **locale_id** lines from yml file, **locale_id** nevertheless appears in log. Rails add it by itself:
```Fixture Insert (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "translations" ("id", "key", "value", "is_proc", "locale_id") VALUES (5503, 'sites.menu.index', 'Сайты', 'f', 1019186233)```

Answer (score 1):

If `locale_id` is set, it seems ok; `locale` will be filled by Rails when you need it (the first time you will request it). 1019186233 is the id generated by rais when the fixtures are created.

Most of the time, you do not need to specify ids in fixtures, rails generate them for you, so fixtures like below should be fine (you should not define both `locale`and `locale_id` in the Translation fixture):

*locales.yml:*

```
ru:
  what_ever_attr: value
  ...
```

*translations.yml:*

```
ru_title_translation:
  key: control.base_search_users.panel.title
  value: Поиск пользователей
  interpolations: 
  locale: ru
  is_proc: false
```

Comment: The problem is that Locale records get the same id values as in fixtures yml file, while locale_ids of translations change their values. Thus all translations that should belong to Translation.find(16) after being loaded from yml fixtures do not belong any existent locale, but to not existent Locale.find(1019186233). why?

Comment: I'm feeling I didn't get your explanations, like I'm missing something very basic

Comment: @zuba Did you try to remove id from both the locale and the translation in fixtures ?

Comment: I apologize for answering late, Baldrick. I tried to remove Locale.id, Translation.id and Translation.locale_id from yaml fixture files. After they were loaded Translation.location_id had the save value for all records but that value didn't match any Locale id. Also for some reason Translation.locale were nil, despite in yaml file it was 'ru'. I suppose that was because Fixture recognized the attribute named locale as a named reference to the certain Locale record it expected to be named *ru*.